# Redirect the users to their seprate pages on login

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am creating a django admin app in which there are two different types of users. One is the admin and another is the simple user.
The problem is I have no idea on how to redirect these users to their own dashboards.
For example, If a user who has created an admin account logs in then he/she should see a admin dashboard. and if a user who has a simple user account logs in then he/she must not be able to see the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I have no time now to help you too much but I will say you to check this Django ClassView: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

You can do something like:

```
class RedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_admin():
            return reverse('admin_dashboard')
        else:
            return reverse('user_dashboard')
```

If you need extra help ask me and I help you later. Good luck!

Edit: In addition, you should check at the admin dashboard view if the user has the admin role, otherwise return a 403 or a 404.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception

Comment: Hey! I understand the Django Class View but the thing is how will I instantiate firstly between the user and admin at the time of login and after that how will be the user redirected to its specific view.

Comment: Hi! Can you elaborate on "instantiate firstly between the user and admin"? I don't understand what do you mean. Thanks!

Comment: I was asking that in order to redirect the user, firstly I have to identify which type of user is logging in, but now I have got it. I missed the `self.request.user.is_admin()` condition previously. One more doubt will `request.user.is_admin()` works if I have a function-based view? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, glad you solve it! Yes it works perfectly in function-based views just make sure your function has a request parameter as this example: (def customview(request)).